# Cant apply Glass shader properly?

Tags: materials, glass

Was wondering what I was doing wrong, Im trying to apply this Eevee glass shader to the "glass" Material I made onto the blue faces I already assigned this material to

Im doing a literal step by step method following this video @6:30
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zzqvGTb6xQI&list=PLvC8NqWpAG3U2MhNbyWzTzPwLEWkCZusD&index=14&t=167s&ab_channel=ArchitectureTopics

But for whatever reason it just doesnt work?
Heres the file
https://drive.google.com/file/d/14Qvm2RQn8jgnpHEYJTVXbRbScSH7M1Y-/view?usp=sharing

This is the glass shader Im trying to apply
https://ibb.co/Ms95TGR

---

Heres a video on what I did
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1y-FHs4hrjC2QTHDoKY8d0Zk_RYvHv9LR/view

Comment: Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Answer (score 0):

change your material in this way

[image]

result (if you decrease alpha to 0.6):

[image]

UPDATE:

i am sorry, i didn't get that you wanted that drag and drop functionality.

I just tried again - and it worked. You can check my video here:

https://youtu.be/U2dKeZhib60

but...please be a little bit patient, because my internet upload is blazingly fa....slow :(

Can you show us a movie/gif so we can see what you are doing (wrong)?

Comment: Thank you, but is there no way to apply the eevee glass shader?
Its not just for this specific instance but in the future as well, if I wanted to use materials from the Blenderkit, when it should be a simple drag and drop, I cant do that anymore because I dont know what the problem is

Comment: it seems to work if I make a new blender scene and do it on a basic cube but if i try to replicate the same in the scene i gave, it doesnt work...

Comment: i did it in your scene. select a window, go to materials tab and change the blend mode.

Comment: I can see your result by doing so, but what I mean is that its supposed to be a drag and drop easy, look I just made a new scene and did a drag and drop and this is what its supposed to look like, just like in the video

But its not working for the scene I made in the drive, so I want to understand what I did wrong so I CAN do drag and drop in the future, otherwise i can solve it this once but then if i encounter this again I wont know what to do

https://ibb.co/h1W160s

Comment: i updated my answer

Comment: Heres a video on what I did
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1y-FHs4hrjC2QTHDoKY8d0Zk_RYvHv9LR/view?usp=sharing